# Meaning of the phrase 'you turned me out' in a song

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, lyrics, african-american-vernacular-english

A line from the song *[You Dropped A Bomb](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/gapband/youdroppedabombonme.html)* goes:

> You turn me out, you turn me on

I understand the meaning of *turn me on*, which basically means 'you sexually arouse me'.

But I can't make out the meaning of the phrase *you turn me out*. What does it mean in this song's context?

Comment: What song, what artist?

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/gapband/youdroppedabombonme.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about song lyrics. Lyrics and poetry generally don't follow normal English usage rules.

Comment: FWIW, this exact lyric pair is found in The Gap Band's [You dropped a bomb on me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Dropped_a_Bomb_on_Me) from 1982, Praxis' [Turn me out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_Me_Out_(Praxis_song)) from 1994, and 2Shoes' "Turn me on(Turn me out)" in 2012. So no, its not a one-off. Quite a common phrase in AAVE actually.

Comment: I have heard that “turn me out” can mean “give me my first homosexual experience”.

Comment: It's street talk for coercing (turning) a young woman into a street walker. Pimping out your girlfriend, in TV detective shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn someone out means to send them away from your home. Not having the entire lyrics, I cannot say whether this meaning applies in this situation.
I tried googling "lyrics you turn me out, you turn me on" but did not get a single hit. Could you please provide the name of the writer, the name of the song and/or possible a link to the text?

Comment: It's 'You Dropped a Bomb on Me' by ' the Gap Band'

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/gapband/youdroppedabombonme.html And it appears to be borderline nonsense, just used to fill in the general theme.

Comment: Oh, so that's sad...by the way, that's the only thing I found - "Ok Your guy friend heard that some guy "turn you out". It is a variation of the phrase "put out" It basically means you had sex with someone and he is bragging" .. does it have any connection with the meaning that in the lyrics?

Comment: Given that the song appears to be in the context of the end of a relationship, I'd say that the meaning is as this answer says - she broke up with him and sent him away.

Comment: I wouldn't call myself an expert on this one phrase, but I did grow up in the same (largely AAVE-speaking) neighborhood in north Tulsa as the Gap Band in the late 70's and early 80's, and I don't think this answer is correct.